# PHP-How to Show file contants in textarea?

Tags: php

I am trying to open a file in textarea . My goal is to view the source code of that file.

But for some reasons it's not working, I am getting :

```
 Resource id #10
```

instead of the file code.

I tried the following code :

```
 <textarea><?php $file=fopen("demo.php","r");
 echo $file;?>
 </textarea>
```

View_source() and highlight_file() both functions are disabled in my host,

Is there any way to implement my existing code?

Any help would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: use `file_get_contents('demo.php');`

Comment: fopen return a resource id, not the text you want. Read the documentation of the function.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`file_get_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to read the file contents

```
 <textarea><?php echo file_get_contents("demo.php"); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `file_get_contents('demo.php');`

```
<textarea><?php echo file_get_contents("demo.php"); ?></textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <textarea><?php $fileContent=file_get_contents("demo.php");
 echo $fileContent;?>
 </textarea>
```